# icon font code (like &#xe192;)is not valid when add it to DOM by using textContent

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, icon-fonts

I'm using google iconfonts in my website.
Normally,the code in HTML is like this:

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE87C;</i>
```

and it will display a 'time' icon on the page:
[the icon will display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CracI.png)

But now I want to add a icon to DOM by using **appendChild()** method.the code is:

```js
var my_element = document.getElementById("icon-div");

// create a i tag
var i = document.createElement("i");
i.className = "material-icons";
i.textContent = "&#xe192;";

// append the tag to my_element
my_element.appendChild(i);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--it should be-->
    <i class="material-icons">&#xe192;</i>

    <!--add it by using appendChild method-->
    <div id="icon-div">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I check the `<i>`(the one in div) in broswer console,its textContent is `"&#xe192;"`,and its innerHTML is `"&amp;#xe192;"`;

So how can I get a icon when I'm add a icon to DOM dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`:

```js
var my_element = document.getElementById("icon-div");

// create a i tag
var i = document.createElement("i");
i.className = "material-icons";
i.innerHTML = "&#xe192;";

// append the tag to my_element
my_element.appendChild(i);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--it should be-->
    <i class="material-icons">&#xe192;</i>

    <!--add it by using appendChild method-->
    <div id="icon-div">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`textContent` assumes you're inserting, well, text; so it escapes the input such that it won't be displayed as HTML.  You want it to be displayed as HTML.

Regarding performance:   `textContent` is [significantly faster](https://jsperf.com/textcontent-vs-innerhtml) than `innerHTML`, because the browser doesn't need to parse the input, so it's not a bad idea to prefer `textContent` when possible -- but in this case you actually need that parsing to occur, so it's necessary to take that small performance hit.  In most real-world situations the difference is negligible, you'd have to be doing tens of thousands of DOM insertions before the difference would be noticeable.

Comment: thank you very much,Daniel!The solution works!But I still have a question:Is this the only way?Because innerHTML may cost too many memory if I have more icons to add into DOM.(even though,for the same icon,I can use cloneNode() method.)

Comment: That's premature optimization. Unless you're dealing with tens of thousands of innerHTML insertions, that should not be an issue at all.

Comment: No trouble!  It's a reasonable question; I added a performance test and a bit of explanation to the answer.